# C# MYSQL Connection

Tags: c#, php, mysql, http, http-tunneling

Briefly, I want to connect remote **MYSQL** *firewalled* database to my C# program

I tried lots of scripts, also I made my script but it was too difficult to be true made a whole web service based DMS

*SSH* is NOT available by the way

The process is few words
**C# <-> HTTP <-> PHP <-> MYSQL**
this is the way I wish it !

**The Question is :**
Can you please point me to a good PHP web-service that can be invoked by a SQL HTML line of code and return me results ?

in advance . please don't say SQLYOG ( as I can't invoke php functions from c# :S )

Thanks =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a month searching this problem, I foung the [Answer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysqlphpxmlprox/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure such a thing would exist, you may need to write your own web service in PHP to perform the specific queries needed by your C# application.

If someone sniffed your application's HTTP connections, they could easily figure out how to call your service and send any SQL queries they wanted to your database.  Then they would be able to select any records, insert, or even delete unless there were extremely complex rules to prevent certain types of queries from going through.

Comment: Don't worry about the security echoes, I don't mention it at all. By the way I don't have specific queries I just asked for a simple DMS system php web service that I can send it my sql and it returns me results

Comment: But is this a C# application you will distribute to many users?  Or just use internally.

Comment: Internally about 2 or 3 users !

Comment: I see, I personally have never seen such a script that exists already, probably for the security reason given. If all it is going to do is execute a query given to it, and return the results, it should be easy to do with a single PHP script.  Do you have any requirements as to how you want to interchange the data, XML, JSON etc?